# What kind of smart lock can I add to my door?

Tags: lock, home-automation

I'm looking to add a smart lock to my door. I don't know much about locksmithing, also not a native speaker, so I'm not sure if this is a "deadbolt" or not.

I was almost decided for the August Smart Lock Pro, but I'd like to confirm if it can be installed directly on my door.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a commercial-style latchset even...I take it this is within a multifamily building, no?

Comment: yes, that looks like a deadbolt ... is there a missing handle?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes it's a multi family building in Argentina :)

Comment: @jsotola You can only lock and unlock, from inside and outside, using the key. Does that answer your question?

Comment: That's a modern latch-set.  You can tell because it has lever handles instead of knobs.   **That means there's a fair chance somebody builds smart lock-sets for that door**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does seem that they are available.

That is a Mortise lock-set, I did a web search for "smart mortise lock" and found a couple, the question is weather they will fit your particular set up ( and can you afford one ).

You will need to do some research. Most of the ones i see are set up with the latch on the bottom and the bolt on the top but yours is opposite that.

Now go forth and conquer.

If you live in a big city find a dedicated locksmith/lock-set retailer.